# Can't pass through variable from collection select in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use a collection select and from there go to my user_show page, but I can't seem to figure out how to send the selected variable through to be displayed.

Here is my current code:

```
<%= form_tag user_path(:id), :method => :post do %>
  <%= collection_select(:user, :id, User.all, :id, :name) %>
  <button type="submit">Sign In</button>
<% end %>
```

This is the closest I've gotten, but it is reading the :id as id.  What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Your [collection_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select) should be like this (with explanation of each field):

```
collection_select(
    :user, # field namespace
    :user_id, # field name
    # result of these two params will be: <select name="user[user_id]">

    # then you should specify some collection or array of rows.
    # In your example it is:
    User.all,

    # then you should specify methods for generating options
    :id, # this is name of method that will be called for every row, result will be set as key
    :name, # this is name of method that will be called for every row, result will be set as value

# as a result, every option will be generated by the following rule:
# 'user' is an element in the collection or array
)
```

So, change your `collection_select` to this:

```
<%= collection_select(:user, :user_id, User.all, :id, :name) %>
```

Comment: is there any way I can access the user through the :id in params (as oppose to the user_id)?

Comment: This is Rails convention for `collection_select `.  Why do you want to access using `id` as opposed to `user_id`? Can you just print the `params` hash in your controller when you submit the form? `puts params.inspect` and show the output?

Comment: Also, if there is no hard requirement for using `form_tag`, use `form_for` (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) that will make life easier for you. The general rule of thumb is, if your form is backed by a model, you should use `form_for` else use `form_tag`.

Comment: I am using show for two forms and one is sending the id and this is sending the user_id...is there another way I can solve this problem?

Comment: If you use `<%= collection_select(:user, :user_id, User.all, :id, :name) %>` does that work as expected?

Comment: That still sends the user_id through as params.  I fixed the issue by creating a separate action and route for my collection select form and then redirecting the user.id to my show action in my users controller--although that does feel like a "hacky" way to do things.  Any advice I would greatly appreciate!  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Glad to know that your problem is fixed. If the answer helped you, consider accept/upvoting the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need:

```
<%= form_tag user_path(:id), :method => :post do %>
  <%= collection_select(:user, :user_id, User.all, :id, :name) %>
  <button type="submit">Sign In</button>
<% end %>
```